# Data Validation in C

Tags: c, validation

I was trying out a simple program in **C** for validating user data. The program is supposed to identify whether a user entered character is a number, alphabet or a special character.

Somehow , the code identifies every kind of input character as a number. I have appended the code below, I'd be grateful if someone could kindly point out where I'm going wrong ?

//Program to take input from the user and determine whether it is character, number, or a special character

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>


    char ch;

int main()

{
     clrscr();

    printf("Enter a character \n");
    scanf("%c \n",ch);

    if ((ch>='A'&& ch<='Z')||(ch>='a'&& ch<='z') )
    {
        printf("The character entered is an alphabet \n" );

    }
     else if ((ch>=0)&&(ch<=9))
    {
        printf("Character entered is an number \n");
    }


    else
    {
        printf("Character entered is a special character");

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You might want to clean up that code block

Comment: Consider using `isalpha()` and `isdigit()` from `<ctypes.h>`

Comment: BTW, Arun, that's a good way to ask a question.  You provided everything we needed to diagnose (the code and what's going wrong) without being excessively verbose.  Just letting you know (and upvoting the question), and hoping we get more such questions from you in the future.

Answer (score 4):

`scanf` accepts a *pointer* as the argument for `%c`.  In other words,

```
scanf("%c \n",ch);
```

should be written as:

```
scanf("%c\n",&ch);
```

Without the reference operator (`&`), `scanf` receives the *value* of `ch`.  In this case, the value is garbage, because `ch` is unset.*  Referencing `ch` gives `scanf` a *pointer to* `ch`, not `ch` itself, so `scanf` can modify the value of `ch` by dereferencing the pointer (using the dereference operator, `*`).

There's also the issue with digit checking that [Himadri mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464654/data-validation-in-c/3464690#3464690).

* This is actually *undefined behaviour*.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, Arun very silly mistake.
In your second condition in else if you have to right 0 and 9 in single quotation mark.

So, your code will be -

```
if ((ch>='A'&& ch<='Z')||(ch>='a'&& ch<='z') )
{
    printf("The character entered is an alphabet \n" );

}
 else if ((ch>='0')&&(ch<='9'))
{
    printf("Character entered is an number \n");
}
else
{
    printf("Character entered is a special character");

}
```

May be this is the only mistake. Now, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

A few comments on style:

1. conio.h and clrscr() are non-standard.
2. Global variables are bad (`char ch`). Declaring them non-static is also bad.
3. Always check the return value of `scanf`. This will help you catch input format errors.
   In this case, as we need to just a single character, `getchar` is more appropriate.

This is how I would've written this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
  int ch; /* We use an int because it lets us check for EOF */
  printf("Enter a character: ");
  fflush(stdout); /* Remember to flush the output stream */
  ch = getchar();
  if (ch == EOF)
    {
      printf("end-of-file or input-error\n");
      return 1;
    }
  if (isalpha(ch))
    printf("The character entered is an alphabet\n" );    
  else if (isdigit(ch))
    printf("Character entered is an number\n");    
  else
    printf("Character entered is a special character\n");    
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Global variables aren't *always* bad.  He's learning; relax.  Your rewrite may cause too much confusion, too; it's introducing `getchar`, `fflush` (which is ugly), `EOF`, and `ctype.h` and functions.

Comment: @strager OK, he can use them when he is weaned :-)